# ¿Alguien me puede orientar porque la list que obtengo de la base de datos no me deja introducirla en el recycler?

Tags: java, android, lista, bucle-for, recyclerview

EDITO: Soy novato en java y Android y este es mi primer post aquí, espero no cometer más fallos que ya hice mal en preguntar en el foro inglés. Estoy realizando una aplicación la cual recupera una lista de negocios que tengo que filtrar por distritos (getdistro) que luego meto en un recycler y para ello me he creado un for each.
Pues si creo una lista a mano va perfecto todo, pero si uso la lista de la base de datos no funciona.
Os dejo el metodo que estoy usando, ahora mismo usando la lista a mano

```
   //Muestro la Lista de Negocios
    public void mostrarResultados (List<Negocios> lista_negocios_base_datos)
    {
        Log.d("ETIQUETA_LOG", "Lista de Negocios de la base de datos = " + lista_negocios_base_datos);

        //Si añado una lista nueva si me funciona correcto, algo pasa con la lista de la base de datos
        List<Negocios> lista_negocios = new ArrayList<Negocios>();
        Negocios n1 = new Negocios(0, 0, "https://i.postimg.cc/W12LLF80/cero.jpg", "Bazar y alimentación Fang", "Tienda típica china con casi de todo.Alimentación, bebidas, droguería, ferretería, papelería, juguetes, lencería, etc.", "9:30 – 24:00", "Avenida de Méjico, 10", "https://g.page/bazarfang?share", "36.69304034794886, -6.128592426981506");
        Negocios n2 = new Negocios(0, 2, "https://i.postimg.cc/W12LLF80/cero.jpg", "Bazar y alimentación Fang", "Tienda típica china con casi de todo.Alimentación, bebidas, droguería, ferretería, papelería, juguetes, lencería, etc.", "9:30 – 24:00", "Avenida de Méjico, 10", "https://g.page/bazarfang?share", "36.69304034794886, -6.128592426981506");
        lista_negocios.add(n1);
        lista_negocios.add(n2);
        Log.d("ETIQUETA_LOG", "Lista de Negocios a dedo = " + lista_negocios);

        //Recuperamos el Intent con el numero de distrito tocado
        int distrito_seleccionado = getIntent().getIntExtra("distrito", 0);

        //Creo una lista nueva de Negocios por cada Distrito, que solo lleva negocios del distrito seleccionado
        List<Negocios> lista_negocios_distrito = new ArrayList<Negocios>();

        // Con este for each obtengo todos los negocios que pertenecen al distrito seleccionado
       for (Negocios negocios : lista_negocios)
        {
          if (negocios.getDistro() == distrito_seleccionado)
            {
               lista_negocios_distrito.add(negocios);
            }
        }

        //Añado la lista_negocios al adapter que a su vez lo coloca en el recycler
        this.recyclerViewNegocios = findViewById(R.id.recicler_negocios);
        this.adapterListaNegocios = new AdapterListaNegocios(lista_negocios_distrito);
        this.recyclerViewNegocios.setAdapter(this.adapterListaNegocios);

        //Defino el estilo de la lista / la distribución
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager =  new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        this.recyclerViewNegocios.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }
```

Os dejo un ejemplo de la lista que me llega de la base de datos

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "distro": 0,
    "foto": "https://i.postimg.cc/W12LLF80/cero.jpg",
    "nombre": "Bazar y alimentación Fang",
    "informacion": "Tienda típica china con casi de todo.Alimentación, bebidas, droguería, ferretería, papelería, juguetes, lencería, etc.",
    "horario": "9:30 – 24:00",
    "direccion": "Avenida de Méjico, 10",
    "enlace_maps": "https://g.page/bazarfang?share",
    "coordenadas": "36.69304034794886, -6.128592426981506"
  }
]
```

Si copio el log de cada lista, se ven asi.
lista_negocios_base_datos

```
[{id=0.0, distro=0.0, foto=https://i.postimg.cc/W12LLF80/cero.jpg, nombre=Bazar y alimentación Fang, informacion=Tienda típica china con casi de todo.Alimentación, bebidas, droguería, ferretería, papelería, juguetes, lencería, etc., horario=9:30 – 24:00, direccion=Avenida de Méjico, 10, enlace_maps=https://g.page/bazarfang?share, coordenadas=36.69304034794886, -6.128592426981506}]
```

lista_negocios esta es la que hago a mano

```
[Negocios{id=0, distro=0, foto='https://i.postimg.cc/W12LLF80/cero.jpg', nombre='Bazar y alimentación Fang', informacion='Tienda típica china con casi de todo.Alimentación, bebidas, droguería, ferretería, papelería, juguetes, lencería, etc.', horario='9:30 – 24:00', direccion='Avenida de Méjico, 10', enlace_maps='https://g.page/bazarfang?share', coordenadas='36.69304034794886, -6.128592426981506'}, Negocios{id=0, distro=2, foto='https://i.postimg.cc/W12LLF80/cero.jpg', nombre='Bazar y alimentación Fang', informacion='Tienda típica china con casi de todo.Alimentación, bebidas, droguería, ferretería, papelería, juguetes, lencería, etc.', horario='9:30 – 24:00', direccion='Avenida de Méjico, 10', enlace_maps='https://g.page/bazarfang?share', coordenadas='36.69304034794886, -6.128592426981506'}]
```

Creo que la clase Obtener datos no esta mal, pero la dejo también por si acaso.

```
public class ObtenerDatos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Negocios>> {

    private static final String URL_NEGOCIOS = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/anmoraque/basedatosdesavio/negocios/";

    private Context actividad_llamante;//MainActivity

    public ObtenerDatos(Context context)
    {
        this.actividad_llamante = context;
    }

    //En este método, se lleva a cabo la comunicación HTTP
    @Override
    protected List<Negocios> doInBackground(Void... vacio) {

        List<Negocios> lista_negocios = null;
        //Aquí vamos a poner la ruta
        URL url = null;
        //Esta clase representa el mensajes / la comunicación http
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        //Este objeto me ayuda a (des)serializar JSON a JAVA
        Gson gson = null;
        //Leo el cuerpo del mensaje
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        try {
            //El proceso de comunicación es susceptible de lanzar una execepción
            //por eso, vamos a agruparlo en un try-catch
            url = new URL(URL_NEGOCIOS);
            Log.d("ETIQUETA_LOG", "URL búsqueda url = " + url);
            //Porque sé que el tipo de conexión es HTTP
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //Consultar, obtener info del servidor, no envío nada (el cuerpo de la petición ,va vacío)
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //HTTP_OK es 200
            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                Log.d("ETIQUETA_LOG", "La conexión ha ido bien! - Respuesta OK");
                //Accedo al cuerpo de la respuesta httpURLConnection.getInputStream()
                //Uso la clase InputStream para leer ese cuerpo
                Log.d("ETIQUETA_LOG", "Obtenidos " +httpURLConnection.getContentLength() + " bytes" );
                Log.d("ETIQUETA_LOG", "TIPO MIME " +httpURLConnection.getContentType() );
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                //Para pasar el cuerpo de JSON a la lista de negocios
                gson = new Gson();
                lista_negocios = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, List.class);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ETIQUETA_LOG", "Algo ha salido mal", e);
        } finally {
            //Liberar recursos
            try {
                inputStreamReader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        }

        return lista_negocios;
    }

    //Este otro método, es invocado, al finalizar la conexión
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Negocios> resultadoListaNegocios
    ) {

        Log.d("ETIQUETA_LOG", "en onPostExecute ... comunicación terminada");
        //¿Cómo le aviso a la clase PantallaNegociosActivity que he acabado ?¿
        PantallaNegociosActivity actividad_negocios = ((PantallaNegociosActivity) this.actividad_llamante);
        actividad_negocios.mostrarResultados(resultadoListaNegocios);

    }
}
```

Gracias por todo.

Comment: Y porqué dices que no te funciona?

Comment: No me rellena el recycler, no sale ningún error pero no funciona. Si creo un negocio a pelo en lista_negocios_distrito, si me rellena el recycler. Y la lista_negocios que obtengo de la base de datos llega bien porque la leo en el log. Por eso creo que el fallo está en el for.

Comment: Verifica que estés recibiendo el valor correcto en `getIntExtra("distrito", 0)`

Comment: Si es el correcto, tengo un log con el distrito tocado. Como te comenté si añado negocios a dedo a lista_negocios me los pone bien, cada uno en su distrito. Igual la lista que me llega no esta bien diseñada y no consigue leer los negocios.

Comment: Acabo de editar el post con nueva información, por si ves algo nuevo, gracias

Comment: Lo primero que debes revisar es que la lista resultadoListaNegocios en  onPostExecute() en verdad tiene elementos.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO: El error esta en la clase ObtenerDatos. Como lo tengo es muy genérico la clase list. Y no me la reconocía como lista de negocios.

```
            //Para pasar el cuerpo de JSON a la lista de negocios
            gson = new Gson();
            lista_negocios = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, List.class);
```

Lo tipeo así y funciona correcto.

```
            gson = new Gson();
            //Pasar el tipo lista a Negocios
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Negocios>>(){}.getType();
            lista_negocios = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, listType);
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda, todo solucionado